# Zend permission RBAC / Error calling class

Tags: php, zend-framework3, rbac

I'm developping an app with Zend-framework 3 which needs user's role management. I'm using **zend-permission-rbac** component to do so.

But i keep having an error :

**File:**
/home/myhost/ppvc/module/User/src/Service/RbacManager.php:77

**Message:**
Class 'Zend\Permissions\Rbac\Rbac' not found

Here's a part of the stack trace if it can help :

- /home/myhost/ppvc/module/User/src/Service/RbacManager.php(116): User\Service\RbacManager->init()
- /home/myhost/ppvc/module/User/src/Controller/Plugin/AccessPlugin.php(25): User\Service\RbacManager->isGranted(NULL, 'user.manage', Array)
- [internal function]: User\Controller\Plugin\AccessPlugin->__invoke('user.manage')

This error pop when i instatiate my Rbac container for the first time :

```
  public function init($forceCreate = false)
{
    if ($this->rbac!=null && !$forceCreate) {
        // Already initialized; do nothing.
        return;
    }

    // If user wants us to reinit RBAC container, clear cache now.
    if ($forceCreate) {
        $this->cache->removeItem('rbac_container');
    }

    // Try to load Rbac container from cache.
    $result = false;
    $this->rbac = $this->cache->getItem('rbac_container', $result);
    if (!$result)
    {
        // Create Rbac container.
        $rbac = new Rbac();
        $this->rbac = $rbac;
.....
```

Also i'm calling my Rbac class correctly :

```
use Zend\Permissions\Rbac\Rbac;
```

I can't undestand where this error come from, it looks like the vendor/zend-permissions-rbac folder isn't "read" by the app. 
I 've updated the **composer.json** and **composer.lock** files and check them, my module is correctly called (composer.json):

```
"zendframework/zend-permissions-rbac": "^3.0",
```

I'm following this tutorial : [Role-Based Access Control](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Role_Based_Access_Control.html)

Any help is welcome ! (Sorry if i made mistakes, english is not my language)

EDIT : i've checked my PHP verion for return type declarations (Because the Rbac module is full of it), but i'm in 7.2 so no problem with that.

Maxime

Comment: This's php error. It's mean something messed up about autoload. It's basicly can't find the class file. Did you try `dump autoload` on composer?

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks for your answer ! Yep i tried `coposer dump autoload` and it change nothing, i'm wondering if it could be the version of the RBAC component who would contain an error ?

Answer (score -1):

Another option to consider is having permissions being managed as a separate service so as you scale up and add more functionality policies can be easily managed. https://cerbos.dev is one example.